# Solr 8 not working when trying to start Solr: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /opt/solr-8.11.1/server/NONE is not a valid keystore?

Tags: java, ssl, solr, solr8

I am trying to setup Solr 8.11.1 on a new server that is running RHEL 8.
I followed all of the steps listed in the Solr guide (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/taking-solr-to-production.html)

I pretty much was able to follow the guide with no issue up until the part where it checks the progress (where I'm supposed to start solr). That's when I try to start Solr and see the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: /opt/solr-8.11.1/server/NONE is not a valid keystore".

I ran the install script that comes packaged with Solr and which the guide says to run. I kept all the default values. So I'm not sure why I'm getting this issue. I did set "SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=false" in the /etc/default/solr.in.sh file. Yet I still get that error when I try to start solr. Any ideas on why I'm getting it and how to resolve it? Thank you in advance!

==========================================================================

/etc/default/solr.in.sh:

```
SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=/opt/solr-8.11.1/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=/opt/solr-8.11.1/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SOLR_SSL_CHECK_PEER_NAME=true
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=JKS
```

==========================================================================

Solr Log:

> 2022-02-04 20:52:10.610 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.u.log Logging
> initialized @1276ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog 2022-02-04
> 20:52:10.878 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-9.4.44.v20210927;
> built: 2021-09-27T23:02:44.612Z; git:
> 8da83308eeca865e495e53ef315a249d63ba9 332; jvm 1.8.0_312-b07
> 2022-02-04 20:52:10.898 INFO  (main) [   ]
> o.e.j.d.p.ScanningAppProvider Deployment monitor
> [file:///opt/solr-8.11.1/server/contexts/] at interval 0 2022-02-04
> 20:52:11.173 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor NO
> JSP Support for /solr, did not find
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet 2022-02-04 20:52:11.185 INFO
> (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.session DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
> 2022-02-04 20:52:11.185 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.session No
> SessionScavenger set, using defaults 2022-02-04 20:52:11.187 INFO
> (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.session node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
> 2022-02-04 20:52:11.240 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.u.c.SSLConfigurations
> Setting javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword 2022-02-04 20:52:11.241 INFO
> (main) [   ] o.a.s.u.c.SSLConfigurations Setting
> javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword 2022-02-04 20:52:11.248 INFO  (main)
> [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Using logger factory
> org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory 2022-02-04 20:52:11.252
> INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter  ___      _
> Welcome to Apache Solr™ version 8.11.1 2022-02-04 20:52:11.252 INFO
> (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter / **| ***| |* _   Starting in
> standalone mode on port 8983 2022-02-04 20:52:11.252 INFO  (main) [
>
> ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter _* / _ \ | '*|  Install dir: /opt/solr
> 2022-02-04 20:52:11.253 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter
> |***/___/*|_|    Start time: 2022-02-04T20:52:11.253Z 2022-02-04
> 20:52:11.264 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrPaths Using system
> property solr.solr.home: /var/solr/data 2022-02-04 20:52:11.264 INFO
> (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig Loading container configuration
> from /var/solr/data/solr.xml 2022-02-04 20:52:11.341 INFO  (main) [
> ] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig MBean server found:
> com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@7bedc48a, but no JMX reporters
> we re configured - adding default JMX reporter. 2022-02-04
> 20:52:11.671 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.h.c.HttpShardHandlerFactory Host
> whitelist initialized: WhitelistHostChecker [whitelistHosts=null,
> whitelist HostCheckingEnabled=true] 2022-02-04 20:52:11.703 WARN
> (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.s.i.Http2SolrClient Create Http2SolrClient with
> HTTP/1.1 transport since Java 8 or lower versions does not  support
> SSL + HTTP/2 2022-02-04 20:52:11.760 ERROR (main) [   ]
> o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Could not start Solr. Check solr/home
> property and the logs 2022-02-04 20:52:11.782 ERROR (main) [   ]
> o.a.s.c.SolrCore null => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error
> instantiating shardHandlerFactory class [Http ShardHandlerFactory]:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: /opt/solr-8.11.1/server/NONE is not a
> valid keystore
> at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:56)
> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error instantiating
> shardHandlerFactory class [HttpShardHandlerFactory]:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: /opt/solr-
> 8.11.1/server/NONE is not a valid keystore
> at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:56)
> ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83
> ef36b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
> at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:696)
> ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83ef36b42ed1223c14b50
>
> - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
>   at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:287)
>   ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83ef3
>   6b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
>   at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:184)
>   ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83ef36b42ed1223c14b5
>   0 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:140)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:731)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:755)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927 ]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
>   ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
>   ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
>   ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:426)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1907)
>   ~[jetty-xml-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
>   ~[jetty-xml-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218) ~[start.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491) ~[start.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77) ~[start.jar:9.4.44.v20210927] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: /opt/solr-8.11.1/server/NONE is not a
>   valid keystore
>   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.createHttpClient(Http2SolrClient.java:234)
>   ~[solr-solrj-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83e
>   f36b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:57]
>   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.(Http2SolrClient.java:159)
>   ~[solr-solrj-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83ef36b42ed12
>   23c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:57]
>   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient$Builder.build(Http2SolrClient.java:857)
>   ~[solr-solrj-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83ef36
>   b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:57]
>   at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory.init(HttpShardHandlerFactory.java:319)
>   ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e
>   83ef36b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
>   at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:51)
>   ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83
>   ef36b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
>   ... 53 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /opt/solr-8.11.1/server/NONE is not a valid keystore
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:50)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:1203)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:322)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:244)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.doStart(HttpClient.java:255)
>   ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
>   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.createHttpClient(Http2SolrClient.java:232)
>   ~[solr-solrj-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83e
>   f36b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:57]
>   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.(Http2SolrClient.java:159)
>   ~[solr-solrj-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83ef36b42ed12
>   23c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:57]
>   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient$Builder.build(Http2SolrClient.java:857)
>   ~[solr-solrj-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83ef36
>   b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:57]
>   at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory.init(HttpShardHandlerFactory.java:319)
>   ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e
>   83ef36b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
>   at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:51)
>   ~[solr-core-8.11.1.jar:8.11.1 0b002b11819df70783e83
>   ef36b42ed1223c14b50 - janhoy - 2021-12-14 13:50:55]
>   ... 53 more 2022-02-04 20:52:11.803 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler Started
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@11bb571c{/solr,file:///opt/solr-8.11.1/server/solr-webap
>   p/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/opt/solr-8.11.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp}
>   2022-02-04 20:52:11.926 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector
>   Started ServerConnector@383dc82c{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8983}
>   2022-02-04 20:52:11.926 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started
>   @2594ms 2022-02-04 20:53:00.999 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ]
>   o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@383dc82c{SSL, (ssl,
>   http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8983} 2022-02-04 20:53:00.999 INFO
>   (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.e.j.s.session node0 Stopped scavenging
>   2022-02-04 20:53:01.007 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ]
>   o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler Stopped
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@11bb571c{/solr,null,STOPPED}{/opt/solr-8.11.1

Comment: I was able to get Solr 7.7 to work just fine using similar steps posted on https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/taking-solr-to-production.html. It seems like there is something that is causing Solr not to run for me in Solr 8.X, but I'm not sure what it is. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Are you by chance running on an SELinux Enabled host? We just noticed this same exact issue, and when we moved Solr to a non-selinux host, it worked fine. I'm wondering if there's an underlying issue with Solr+Jetty and selinux.

Comment: Yes our host is running SELinux, but one of our admins added the necessary configs to allow Solr to work with SELinux. However, even with those changes Solr still did not start properly and we still got the same errors. We then tried to replicate it on a non-SELinux host and got it to work. So we know now that it is an environment related issue. Now we are thinking that it may be a FIPS issue that is preventing Solr from working since the non-SELinux host also did not have FIPS enabled. We are going to try to get the FIPS settings in place and I'll update here once that's done.

Comment: I've tried looking online for resources on how to get Solr to work in a FIPS environment, but have only found resources related to third parties using Solr in their setup with FIPS. I can't even follow their steps since I don't even have those third party apps running in my system. So does anyone have any experience or advice on how to get Solr working within a FIPS enabled environment?

Comment: @ev0lution37 You may find resolution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387682/how-do-you-get-solr-8-11-to-run-on-a-fips-enabled-environment/71415193?noredirect=1#comment126233199_71415193

Answer (score 0):

So my team and I FINALLY got it working after trying numerous ways. So I thought I'd go ahead and share this info in hopes that the next person will find this info useful to them. First we found out that our RHEL 8.5 system has FIPS enabled. So trying to start Solr without a FIPS compliant keystore just wouldn't work. We kept trying to figure out how to create a FIPS compliant keystore, but were unable to. Then one of our team members found this link https://github.com/kvbutler/solr8-rehl8.5-fips-sip online. This pretty much got us 90% there. We just had to make a few tweaks on our end such as having Solr use Java 11 openjdk instead of Java 8, making a few SELinux changes, and a few other changes to the solr.in.sh file as needed for our setup, but otherwise the guide pretty much got us to our solution. Hope this helps!